# Kubernetes - show help for a command but only show examples

Tags: kubernetes, command

Is it possible to get the help for a k8s command but only show the Examples section of the help?

For example, if I run:

```
kubectl run --help
```

It outputs different sections, but I only want to see examples on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This command only show line 2 to line 30

```sh
kubectl run --help | head -n30 | tail -n28
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many other help pages, K8s help docs come in this order:

1. Description
2. Examples
3. Options
4. Usage

you could use **sed** to cut out the part you need:

```
kubectl run --help | sed -n "/Examples:/,/Options:/p"
```

or better:

```
kubectl run --help | sed -n "/Examples:/,/Options:/p" | grep -v "Options:"
```